# Memory leak in MBProgressHUD

Tags: iphone, memory-management

In below code there is about 3MB of leak.If I remove `[self.view addSubview:progressDialog];`
then their is no leak.

```
    -(void)showProgressDialog:(NSString*)title setTimer:(BOOL)isTimerSet
    {
        progressDialog = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)]; 
        [progressDialog setLabelText:title];
        progressDialog.dimBackground=YES;
        [self.view addSubview:progressDialog];//Leak is here
        [progressDialog show:YES];
    }

    -(void)hideProgressDialog
    {
        if(progressDialog !=nil)
        {
            [progressDialog hide:YES];
            [progressDialog removeFromSuperview];
            [progressDialog release];
            progressDialog = nil;
        }
    }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you are not releasing it progressDialog or if it is ivar, then use property instead of ivar, and synthesize it, then follow this approch

```
   MBProgressHUD *obj = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)]; 
   self.progressDialog=obj;
   [obj release];
```

like this

```
    MBProgressHUD *obj = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)]; 
    self.progressDialog=obj;
    [obj release];        
    [self.progressDialog setLabelText:title];
    self.progressDialog.dimBackground=YES;
    [self.view addSubview:self.progressDialog];//Leak is here
    [self.progressDialog show:YES];
```

Comment: Actually leak is in CGRectMake i.e. initWithFrame:CGRectMake()

Comment: this init method is returning an object with a retaincount increment that stores in progressDialog, and next time if you press the button it again increase one, without releasing it. if you release it. i hope it will be resolved

Comment: I m release it in hideProgressDialog method.